# GAMs spatial analysis (mgcv) - adding a map for visualization

Tags: r, geospatial, country, mgcv

I have created a spatial analysis with mgcv, basically:

```
library(mgcv)
spatial_analysis <- gam(target_parameter ~ s(Lon, Lat), data = df, method = "REML")
plot(spatial analysis)
```

The plot comes out fine, with the contour lines, etc... but I want to include some kind of map for reference, and I feel like I have tried everything and can't find a solution. Just FYI, I am looking to map the coastline of Israel...

(PS: it seems the plot can't be delivered to `ggplot()`)

Comment: please add a data sample, so we can see your problem.

Comment: Hi Santiago, thanks for the reply!
My data set includes 20,000 rows so i'm not  quite sure how to add a data sample.. also, i wanted to add an image of the resulting plot (without the map) but i couldn't figure out how to add an image either... any advice?

Comment: You can add sample data (not your real dataset). You can use functions like rnorm to generate random numbers. The important thing is generating a data sample that has the same structure as your real data. So we can use that sample to see the problem.

Comment: In fact, I am quite sure that the plot can be done with ggplot, and I would like to see your data structure to plot it with ggplot. And then is easy to add a map.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Since 2021 a few new tools have become available which makes this relatively straightforward today. Here is a reproducible example. In this example, we do a (stupid) spatial analysis of county areas in North Carolina (NC) using `mgcv`, and then display the smooth estimates (contours) on a map of North Carolina using `sf` and `ggplot2`.

The tricky part is creating a mask of NC to restrict the display of the contours within the boundaries of our map. And we use `tidymv` to extract the model estimates in an expanded and "tidy" form that is easily passed to ggplot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(mgcv)

# Import a map of North Carolina from sf shapefiles 
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
```

We need to calculate the location of each county as a point estimate (centroid) for the spatial analysis. So we calculate the centroid of each polygon in geometry, extract the X and Y coordinates, convert to a tibble for convenience, and finally rename the coordinates as lat (latitude) and long (longitude)

```
# Country centroid coordinates (in latitude and longitude)
coords <- nc %>%
  st_centroid() %>%
  st_coordinates() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(long = X, lat = Y)
```

Now we have our longitude and latitude coordinates of each county, we run our spatial analysis predicting the size of each county by its location (longitude, latitude).

```
# Create a data frame for modelling
df <- as_tibble(nc) %>%
  select(-geometry) %>%
  bind_cols(coords)

# Model area by location (lat, long)
fit <- gam(AREA ~ s(long, lat), data = df)

# Get the predictions in a form suitable for ggplot2
predictions <- tidymv::predict_gam(fit)
```

Our tibble of estimates looks like this.

```
# A tibble: 2,500 × 4
long   lat   fit se.fit
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
-84.1  34.1 0.134 0.0247
-83.9  34.1 0.135 0.0238
-83.7  34.1 0.136 0.0230
-83.6  34.1 0.137 0.0223
-83.4  34.1 0.138 0.0217
-83.2  34.1 0.139 0.0211
-83.0  34.1 0.141 0.0207
-82.9  34.1 0.142 0.0203
-82.7  34.1 0.143 0.0199
-82.5  34.1 0.144 0.0196
# ℹ 2,490 more rows
```

But we will need to create a mask of the NC map so we can view the mgcv contours behind it.

```
# first create a solid bounding box capturing the entire map
nc_grid <- st_make_grid(nc, n = c(1, 1))

# then create a map of the external borders of NC (i.e., remove shared borders)
nc_borders <- st_union(nc)

# then subtract the external borders from our bounding box to create an NC-
# shaped hole
nc_mask <- st_difference(nc_grid, nc_borders) %>%
  st_as_sf()
```

Once we have our estimates and our mask, we can combine both using ggplot. Here we plot our estimates (contours) under the mask so as to mask any contours which fall outside the boundaries of NC

```
ggplot(predictions, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = fit)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = fit), color = "white") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_mask, inherit.aes = F)
```

[image: nc contours]